# How to concatenate data frames with unequal number of rows and different column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate four data frames with an unequal number of rows and different column names. Here I am placing my code and output what I am getting.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col':[33,44,55,67], 'Col1':[44,55,55,555]})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col2':[33,44], 'Col3':[22,22]})
data3 = pd.DataFrame({'Col4':[33,44,44], 'Col5':[22,22,44]})
data4 = pd.DataFrame({'Col6':[33], 'Col7':[22], 'Col8':[44]})


data5 = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3, data4])
data5
```

here is my actual output

[image]

what I am expecting is:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the output size you d expect if different number of rows given? Max of them all?

Comment: Could you also please describe what have you tried to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1`, but first repeat values for match maximal lengths of rows:

```
dfs = [data1, data2, data3, data4]

maxlen = len(max(dfs, key=len))
print (maxlen)
4

dfs = [pd.concat([x] * int(np.ceil(maxlen / len(x))), ignore_index=True).iloc[:maxlen] 
       for x in dfs]
data5 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

print (data5)
   Col  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  Col8
0   33    44    33    22    33    22    33    22    44
1   44    55    44    22    44    22    33    22    44
2   55    55    33    22    44    44    33    22    44
3   67   555    44    22    33    22    33    22    44
```

Comment: i am getting error 'str' object has no attribute concate. because in my original dataframe there is text in rows. how to overcome this error

Comment: @SuneelKumar - hmm, I think problem is not `text`, try change sample data and working well.

Comment: @SuneelKumar - Are in `dfs` list `DataFrames` ?

Comment: yeah it's working fine. It was my mistake because i wrote p.concat instead of pd.concat

Comment: @SuneelKumar - Super!

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jezrael

Comment: @SuneelKumar Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)